# restrict the field not accept numbers smaller than 2015

Tags: regex

I am supposed to validate a field controlled by regex. The required format of the value is xxxx.xx (x must be an integer). I have the following and it works well:

```
regex(.,'[0-9]{4}+\.[0-9]{2}')
```

But the first four digits (before the dot) must be at least 2015 (the last year). Please let me know how to do it!

Comment: What input is valid and which is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
^[2-9]\d[1-9][5-9]\.[0-9]{2}$
```

Explanation

[image]

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dK8oQ4/1)

Comment: and what about 2109 or 9000 or 2020

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks

Comment: Actually, you can fine tune eternally until OP clarifies what is necessary. The requirements are too obscure. Your regex matches `9999.99`. No idea what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would implement the desired restirction:

```
(?:201[5-9]|20[2-9][0-9]|2[1-9][0-9]{2}|[3-9][0-9]{3})\.[\d]{2}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rY6nE9/1)

Above is to match

```
2015-2019
2020-2099
2100-2199
3000-9999
```

followed by . and two digits.

Comment: @SebastianProske right. I will correct it. Thanks for finding error.

Comment: @SebastianProske I corrected it. Does it satisfy the criteria?

Comment: 202[0-9]|20[3-9][0-9] is the same as 20[2-9]\d, but it looks correct